# Array aren't copy in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two array in different files ! First in the file named maturi.js and it looks like

```
const BEL2010YEAR12 = [
  {
    question: "",
    hasImage: false,
    isAnswered: false,
    isTextQuestion: true,
    text: "",
    answers: [
      {
        id: "1",
        text: "",
        correct: false,
        userInput: false,
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        text: "",
        correct: false,
        userInput: false,
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        text: "",
        correct: false,
        userInput: false,
      },
      {
        id: "4",
        text: "",
        correct: true,
        userInput: false,
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default {
  BEL2010YEAR12,
};
```

Second file is my App.js where i called maturi (file above) like

```
import { BEL12 } from "../maturi";
```

Then i created another array to copy first which name is **BEL2010YEAR12** (from file above)
So

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState(BEL12.BEL2010YEAR12);
```

The problem is when i edit questions array it is affected to the **BEL12.BEL2010YEAR12** array. How is this possible. I am confused. Why **questions** array changed **BEL12.BEL2010YEAR12** ?
For example if i edit **questions** like

```
questions[0].question = "example";
setQuestions(questions);
```

It will changed array **BEL2010YEAR12** . I dont want that ! Why it changed it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for javascript objects and reference. This is how javascript works and you want it to work that way.

If you make an object (or array) and assign this to multiple variables all the variables reference the same object (array).

If you want a copy google "javascript copy object".

Best way to make a copy is in your case `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourObject))` (this wouldn't make a copy of functions though)

The spread operator (...) as @Mohaimin suggested isn't a good choice for you in your case, because your nested objects inside BEL2010YEAR12 will be still referencing the original.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Can you give example?

Comment: let copyObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(BEL2010YEAR12)); for example. Or let copyQuestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(questions)); after you destructure questions

Comment: i do it like  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState(
    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(BEL12.BEL2010YEAR12))
  ); ! Is it good?

Comment: ye and it is wotk. Thank you so much !

Comment: Right, the spread operator isn't good for deeply nested objects, this is a better solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy the array. If you try to put it directly like you did, it will store the reference, hence effecting the original array. You can read more on [value vs reference in js](https://dmitripavlutin.com/value-vs-reference-javascript/)

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([...BEL12.BEL2010YEAR12]);
```

For deep clones(deeply nested objects):

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(BEL12.BEL2010YEAR12)));
```